# Make a visual object in Flex 4 move along a circular motion path

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4

I can't seem to figure out how to accomplish a fairly simple task: I have a simple graphic and I'd like to apply an "orbiting" effect to it - so that the graphic moves in a circle around an arbitrary point (without rotating around its own center).

```
<s:Ellipse id="circle" width="100" height="100">
  <s:fill>
    <s:SolidColor color="0x000000" />
  </s:fill>
</s:Ellipse>
```

I was trying to do something using `spark.effects.Animate` but couldn't figure out how to configure motion paths - I started thinking about Cartesian vs Polar coordinate systems and appropriate circle equations for each and then realized I was probably over-thinking it. Although I consider this to be a fairly common problem searching the Web yielded no results.

P.S.
I'd like to use Flex 4 as much as possible, so I'd appreciate it if the answers reused Flex 4 classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realize that this is a very old question. However, considering that a google search for `flex 4 circular motion` returns this thread as the very first result, I figured it may be worthwhile to make a small contribution.

Robusto's solution does work - if you don't mind handling the animation updates yourself. If, on the other hand, you'd like to use `spark.effects.Animate`, then using a Sine easer can accomplish the same thing.

```
<s:Sine id="cosine" easeInFraction="0.0" />
<s:Sine id="sine" easeInFraction="1.0" />
```

The `easeInFraction` property specifies what portion of the easing is spent accelerating. For the Sine easer, this is the portion spent climbing up the Sine curve. By setting this fraction to `0.0`, the easer begins at the top of the curve, becoming a Cosine.

A small example (I realize that the main Sequence is a bit verbose. You'd likely want make a new component extending the `spark.effects.Sequence` class instead of having this all in your main application, but this is just to give the general idea):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
               minWidth="955" minHeight="600"
               applicationComplete="move_circle.play([circle])">

    <fx:Declarations>
        <fx:int id="mid_x">500</fx:int>
        <fx:int id="mid_y">300</fx:int>
        <fx:int id="radius">200</fx:int>
        <s:Sine id="cosine" easeInFraction="0.0" />
        <s:Sine id="sine" easeInFraction="1.0" />

        <s:Sequence id="move_circle" repeatCount="0">
            <s:Parallel>
                <s:Animate easer="{cosine}">
                    <s:SimpleMotionPath property="x" valueTo="{mid_x + radius}" />
                </s:Animate>
                <s:Animate easer="{sine}">
                    <s:SimpleMotionPath property="y" valueTo="{mid_y}" />
                </s:Animate>
            </s:Parallel>
            <s:Parallel>
                <s:Animate easer="{sine}">
                    <s:SimpleMotionPath property="x" valueTo="{mid_x}" />
                </s:Animate>
                <s:Animate easer="{cosine}">
                    <s:SimpleMotionPath property="y" valueTo="{mid_y + radius}" />
                </s:Animate>
            </s:Parallel>
            <s:Parallel>
                <s:Animate easer="{cosine}">
                    <s:SimpleMotionPath property="x" valueTo="{mid_x - radius}" />
                </s:Animate>
                <s:Animate easer="{sine}">
                    <s:SimpleMotionPath property="y" valueTo="{mid_y}" />
                </s:Animate>
            </s:Parallel>
            <s:Parallel>
                <s:Animate easer="{sine}">
                    <s:SimpleMotionPath property="x" valueTo="{mid_x}" />
                </s:Animate>
                <s:Animate easer="{cosine}">
                    <s:SimpleMotionPath property="y" valueTo="{mid_y - radius}" />
                </s:Animate>
            </s:Parallel>
        </s:Sequence>
    </fx:Declarations>

    <s:Ellipse id="circle"
               x="{mid_x}" y="{mid_y - radius}"
               width="100" height="100">
        <s:fill>
            <s:SolidColor color="#000000" />
        </s:fill>
    </s:Ellipse>
</s:Application>
```

Comment: i, honestly, don't have the time to test this out but it looks exactly like what i was looking for, accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use trig to find the circumference:

```
var radius = 50;
for (var i:int = 0, imax:int = 359) : void {
    var radians:Number = i * (Math.PI/180);
    pointX = radius * Math.cos(radians);
    pointY = radius * Math.sin(radians);
    // position something at pointX,pointY
}
```

This goes once around a circle and plots a point for each degree. You would probably want to figure out the offsets from x,y for your orbiting and orbited elements so that the former's center would appear to orbit around the latter's.

Comment: where would this code go? i'm trying to stick to using Flex 4 and the effects provided by it, as opposed to writing random AS3 workarounds. should i extend one of the classes?

Comment: This is not a "random AS3 workaround." It's a way to position an element in a circle. As such, you would call it in the updateDisplayList method of the parent container of both objects. You would also create variables to store the current values, and do your positioning using them instead of a loop. I only did a loop here to give you the idea of what happens, but if you're not comfortable using ActionScript maybe this isn't the solution for you.

Comment: oh no, AS3 isn't the problem. i was just hoping for a "cleaner" way to resolve the issue - using one of the classes from spark.effects package. So there's really no way to use spark.effects.Rotate or a customized spark.effects.Animate?